# How to retrieve a array value in magento

Tags: php, magento

For example I need to retrieve a value from this session. How should I do ? Exactly i need to get the "**customer_log_id**".

```
> Array (
>     [core] => Array
>         (
>             [_session_validator_data] => Array
>                 (
>                     [remote_addr] => 127.0.0.1
>                     [http_via] => 
>                     [http_x_forwarded_for] => 
>                     [http_user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5
>                 )
> 
>             [session_hosts] => Array
>                 (
>                     [127.0.0.1] => 1
>                 )
> 
>             [messages] => Mage_Core_Model_Message_Collection
> Object
>                 (
>                     [_messages:protected] => Array
>                         (
>                         )
> 
>                     [_lastAddedMessage:protected] => 
>                 )
> 
>             [visitor_data] => Array
>                 (
>                     [] => 
>                     [server_addr] => 2130706433
>                     [remote_addr] => 2130706433
>                     [http_secure] => 
>                     [http_host] => 127.0.0.1
>                     [http_user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5
>                     [http_accept_language] =>
> en-us,en;q=0.5
>                     [http_accept_charset] =>
> ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
>                     [request_uri] => /currentproject/magento/index.php/customer/account/
>                     [session_id] => 34989ee1673caefec0d887dd41198587
>                     [http_referer] => http://127.0.0.1/currentproject/magento/index.php/customer/account/login/
>                     [first_visit_at] => 2009-12-04 11:20:24
>                     [is_new_visitor] => 
>                     [last_visit_at] => 2009-12-04 11:32:26
>                     [visitor_id] => 208
>                     [last_url_id] => 1399
>                     [catalog_compare_items_count] => 0
>                     [do_customer_login] => 
>                     [customer_id] => 1
>                     [customer_log_id] => 8
>                 )
> 
>             [last_url] => http://127.0.0.1/currentproject/magento/index.php/customer/account/index/
>             [just_voted_poll] => 
>         )
> 
>     [_cookie_revalidate] => 1259926524
>     [customer_base] => Array
>         (
>             [_session_validator_data] => Array
>                 (
>                     [remote_addr] => 127.0.0.1
>                     [http_via] => 
>                     [http_x_forwarded_for] => 
>                     [http_user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5
>                 )
> 
>             [session_hosts] => Array
>                 (
>                     [127.0.0.1] => 1
>                 )
> 
>             [messages] => Mage_Core_Model_Message_Collection
> Object
>                 (
>                     [_messages:protected] => Array
>                         (
>                         )
> 
>                     [_lastAddedMessage:protected] => 
>                 )
> 
>             [id] => 1
>         )
> 
>     [checkout] => Array
>         (
>             [_session_validator_data] => Array
>                 (
>                     [remote_addr] => 127.0.0.1
>                     [http_via] => 
>                     [http_x_forwarded_for] => 
>                     [http_user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5
>                 )
> 
>             [session_hosts] => Array
>                 (
>                     [127.0.0.1] => 1
>                 )
> 
>             [quote_id_1] => 
>         )
> 
>     [catalog] => Array
>         (
>             [_session_validator_data] => Array
>                 (
>                     [remote_addr] => 127.0.0.1
>                     [http_via] => 
>                     [http_x_forwarded_for] => 
>                     [http_user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5
>                 )
> 
>             [session_hosts] => Array
>                 (
>                     [127.0.0.1] => 1
>                 )
> 
>             [messages] => Mage_Core_Model_Message_Collection
> Object
>                 (
>                     [_messages:protected] => Array
>                         (
>                         )
> 
>                     [_lastAddedMessage:protected] => 
>                 )
> 
>         )
> 
>     [newsletter] => Array
>         (
>             [_session_validator_data] => Array
>                 (
>                     [remote_addr] => 127.0.0.1
>                     [http_via] => 
>                     [http_x_forwarded_for] => 
>                     [http_user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5
>                 )
> 
>             [session_hosts] => Array
>                 (
>                     [127.0.0.1] => 1
>                 )
> 
>         )
> 
> )
```

Comment: may i ask where you get this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a['core']['visitor_data']['customer_log_id']
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're trying to retrieve the information from the `$_SESSION` array. There are two ways you can do this. As another poster suggested, you can simply hack it out of the `$_SESSION` superglobal thusly:

```
$logId = $_SESSION['core']['visitor_data']['customer_log_id'];
```

However, this is a bit of a hack to avoid the Magento framework. The better option (from a "correctness" point of view) is to use Magento's session management. So, instead, we have:

```
// we could also skip a step and just use Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->getVisitorData(), 
// but I wanted to add the datatypes for your reference
$session =  Mage::getSingleton("core/session"); // Mage_Core_Model_Session
$customerData = $session->getVisitorData(); // array
$logId = $customerData['customer_log_id']; // int
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks Mastey... U just show me an another new way to get the array value in magento. Many thanks for your answer.